# Exploit by writing/reading arbitrary memory

Tags: c, memory-management, exploit

I'm trying to solve the below challenge as is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void findme() {
    printf("found me\n");
}

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", findme);
    char buf[20];

    while (1) {
        printf(">> ");
        fgets(buf, 20, stdin);

        if (strstr(buf, "get") != NULL) {
            unsigned int idx;
            sscanf(buf, "get %i\n", &idx);

            char *offset = idx;

            char value = *offset;
            printf("%i = 0x%x\n", idx, (unsigned char)value);
        } else if (strstr(buf, "set") != NULL) {
            unsigned char value;
            unsigned int idx;
            sscanf(buf, "set %i %i\n", &idx, &value);

            printf("%i %i", idx, value);

            unsigned int *offset = idx;
            *offset = value;
        } else if (strstr(buf, "wild") != NULL) {
            printf("go wild now\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc test.c -o test -fno-stack-protector -m32
```

Considering that I don't know the address for buf, I assume the return address should be overwritten.
So entering something like

```
set -13012 X
```

would give the option to set arbitrary data to the return address. The thing that confused me was that the value I can set is only a "unsigned char". So how would I set the return address to the address of the "findme" function?

Comment: `scanf("%i"` for `unsigned char` is *wrong* by the way. It will corrupt memory. Is that the point, or is it just a bug?

Comment: And you can set one byte at a time, surely? 4 bytes, so run 4 different set commands.